# Issues when including matlab code in Latex

Tags: errors, listings

I am currently trying to implement my Matlab-Code into `TeX`. Weird enough, when programming a minimum working example, everything works pretty fine. However, when I use my real document, I only get errors. Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbered]{mcode}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
        linewidth=15.5cm,}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[label={hans}, caption=Funktion {\ttfamily setminInt}]
                {"E:/Program Files/MATLAB/projects/master/classes/Customer.m"}
\end{document}
```

Here's the preamble of the original document (although heavily shortened):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip,bibtotoc,liststotoc]{article}

\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}   
\usepackage{setspace}      %fr Zeilenabstand
\usepackage[notindex,nottoc]{tocbibind}  %Inhaltsverzeichnisse erstellen

%zustzliche bentigte Pakete
\usepackage{graphicx}      %Graphik
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  %Mathematik
\usepackage{natbib}       %Zitate
\usepackage{marvosym}      %enthlt Symbole wie das Eurozeichen
\usepackage{eurosym}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage[numbered]{mcode}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Source Code}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
        linewidth=15.5cm,}

\setlength{\parskip}{3pt} % 1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}


\usepackage{mdwlist} 
\usepackage[labelsep=space,justification=centering]{caption}

%\usepackage{hyperref} %erlaubt Links innerhalb des pdf-Dokuments zu erzeugen

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}   %Verhinderung des horizontalen Einrckens zu Beginn eines Absatzes

%Seitenlayout
\topmargin -0.9cm    %Vertikaler Abstand der Kopfzeile von der Bezugslinie
\textheight 25cm    %Abstand der Grundlinie der Kopfzeile zum Haupttext
\textwidth 16.5cm    %Breite des Haupttexts
\footskip 1cm      %Abstand der Grundlinien der letzten Textzeile und der Fuzeile
\voffset -0.5cm     %Vertikale Bezugspunktposition
\hoffset -1.2cm     %Horizontale Bezugspunktposition

\onehalfspacing     %anderthalbzeiliger Abstand

\newcommand{\url}{\;}  %URL im Literaturverzeichnis

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[caption=Funktion {\ttfamily setminInt}]
                    {"E:/Program Files/MATLAB/projects/master/classes/Customer.m"}
\end{document}
```

I always get the error:
("E:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1pcr.fd"))
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 560.

So `miktex` ignores everything that's written in the customer class (the code starts at line 560)

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you should have a look at the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; it improves upon `mcode` in many ways. See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891), for instance. Also, contrary to `mcode`, it's available in MiKTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `ngerman` option to `babel` as this turns on shorthands.  The simplest solution is to turn them off via:

```
\usepackage[shorthands=off,ngerman,english]{babel}
```

Otherwise you can turn off shorthands around the listing input command via:

```
\begingroup
\shorthandoff{"}
\lstinputlisting[caption=Funktion {\ttfamily setminInt}] {"file.m"}
\endgroup
```

In your full example with external `file.m` containing

```
nth
```

this gives:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip,bibtotoc,liststotoc]{article}

\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}   
\usepackage{setspace}      %fr Zeilenabstand
\usepackage[notindex,nottoc]{tocbibind}  %Inhaltsverzeichnisse erstellen

%zustzliche bentigte Pakete
\usepackage{graphicx}      %Graphik
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  %Mathematik
\usepackage{natbib}       %Zitate
\usepackage{marvosym}      %enthlt Symbole wie das Eurozeichen
\usepackage{eurosym}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage[numbered]{mcode}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Source Code}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
        linewidth=15.5cm,}

\setlength{\parskip}{3pt} % 1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}


\usepackage{mdwlist} 
\usepackage[labelsep=space,justification=centering]{caption}

%\usepackage{hyperref} %erlaubt Links innerhalb des pdf-Dokuments zu erzeugen

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}   %Verhinderung des horizontalen Einrckens zu Beginn eines Absatzes

%Seitenlayout
\topmargin -0.9cm    %Vertikaler Abstand der Kopfzeile von der Bezugslinie
\textheight 25cm    %Abstand der Grundlinie der Kopfzeile zum Haupttext
\textwidth 16.5cm    %Breite des Haupttexts
\footskip 1cm      %Abstand der Grundlinien der letzten Textzeile und der Fuzeile
\voffset -0.5cm     %Vertikale Bezugspunktposition
\hoffset -1.2cm     %Horizontale Bezugspunktposition

\onehalfspacing     %anderthalbzeiliger Abstand

\newcommand{\url}{\;}  %URL im Literaturverzeichnis

\begin{document}
xx"ayy

\begingroup
\shorthandoff{"}
\lstinputlisting[caption=Funktion {\ttfamily setminInt}] {"file.m"}
\endgroup

xx"ayy
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh my, it worked! You saved the day, thx :)

Comment: Was about to, but I had a chat with my flatmate

Answer (score 2):

Just add somewhere after loading `listings` the magic code

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\lst@setcatcodes{\catcode`\"=12 }
\makeatother
```

and you won't need any special trick. This is a safe measure; unfortunately there's no interface for it and it would be nice if there was. However, this has the consequence that `babel` shorthands cannot be used in the optional argument. If you need them a different solution is required.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}   

\usepackage[numbered]{mcode}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Source Code}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
        linewidth=15.5cm,}

\usepackage{mdwlist} 
\usepackage[labelsep=space,justification=centering]{caption}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\lstinputlisting}{%
  \begingroup\lst@setcatcodes\Xlst@listinputlisting
}
\newcommand{\Xlst@listinputlisting}[1][]{%
  \endgroup\def\lst@set{#1}%
  % make " other just for absorbing the next argument
  \begingroup\@makeother\"\Xlst@listinputlisting@i
}
\newcommand{\Xlst@listinputlisting@i}[1]{%
  \endgroup
  \IfFileExists{\lst@inputpath#1}
    {\expandafter\lst@InputListing\expandafter{\lst@inputpath#1}}%
    {\filename@parse{\lst@inputpath#1}%
     \edef\reserved@a{\noexpand\lst@MissingFileError{\filename@area\filename@base}%
       {\ifx\filename@ext\relax tex\else\filename@ext\fi}}%
     \reserved@a}%
  \lst@doendpe\@newlistfalse\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
xx"ayy

\lstinputlisting[caption=F\"unktion {\ttfamily setminInt}] {"juliaset.m"}

xx"ayy
\end{document}
```

The idea is to separate absorbing of the optional argument and the mandatory one. The `"` shorthand is removed just for grabbing the argument, just like `\lst@setcatcodes` is valid only when absorbing the optional argument.